# Export method/function in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
export { width as responsiveHeight } from "react-native-responsive-dimensions";
```

I want to export `responsiveHeight` with name `width`. What is correct way to do this? As this is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is opposite. You want to get `responsiveHeight` as `width`.

Try this

```
export { responsiveHeight as width } from "react-native-responsive-dimensions";
```

Answer (score 2):

You're actually doing the opposite, you are taking your width function and add it an alias called responsiveHeight, so you need to do this:

```
export { responsiveHeight } from "react-native-responsive-dimensions";
```

just as simple as that, export width in that way, it should work with no issue.

Comment: Thanks can you tell me what `width as responsiveHeight` this syntax mean?

Comment: By the way responsiveHeight is a function of `react-native-responsive-dimensions`

Comment: `width as responsiveHeight` you are telling your code export the function/variable called width into `react-native-responsive-dimensions` and export it as responsiveHeight, I mean you are exporting that with an alias name, so then when you are importing that function you can import it like this: `import { responsiveHeight } from '../path/to/file'` and not as `width` because you gave an alias.

Answer (score -1):

Try This One.

```
import React from "react";
import {responsive} from "react-native-responsive-ui";

@responsive
export default class Debug extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {width, height} = this.props.window;
        console.log(`New window dimensions: ${width}x${height}`);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use this ?